# Homing Missile Behavior in Java

Tags: java, loops, 2d

Maybe a beginner question, but thank you for reading. I'm working on a 2d Java game in which I have missiles that track the position of an object using the following code. I'd like the missiles to stop homing when they reach a certain minimum displacement from their target, at which point they should fall straight down. Right now, the homing behavior turns off whenever the missile is within the minimum displacement, and turns on again if the displacement increases. **I'd like the behavior to turn off only once, staying off for the remainder of the missile's lifespan.** How can I accomplish this?

```
public void home(int targetX, int targetY, int scale){
    int dy = targetY - y;
    int dx = targetX - x;
    double speed, sep;

    sep = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    speed = scale/sep;

    if(dy > 50 || dx > 50){
        x += dx * speed;
        y += dy * speed;
    }
    else{
        x += 0;
        y += scale;
    }
}
```

Comment: Might belong on gamedev.se...

Answer (score 6):

Add a member variable, such as `boolean homing = true`. Then, change your conditional to something like the following:

```
if (dy < 50 && dx < 50)
    homing = false;

if(homing){
    x += dx * speed;
    y += dy * speed;
}
else{
    x += 0;
    y += scale;
}
```

You basically just need to break the mutual dependence between you missile's behaviour and its state.

Comment: I tried this, but I run into an issue. The compiler complains because, if the first statement evaluates to false, 'homing' will have no value. Then I try to ininitate 'homing' at the top of the method, but both true and false starting values yield the incorrect behavior. Thank you for your answer though. It helps to know that I'm at least on the right track.

Comment: @emmett9001: Don't initialise the variable in your `home` method, instead initialise it in your class constructor. Or, really, any other method **but** `home`. Come to think of it, if you have a `launch` method or something similar that is called whenever the missile is first launched, *that's* the ideal place to put `homing = true`.

Comment: thank you very much for the help! I feel like maybe I should have been able to figure that out on my own...but thank you nonetheless.

Comment: @emmett9001 - If this answer solved your problem, maybe you could mark the question as solved?